# Need help getting DFP and Publisher Revenue from Google Analytics Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-dfp

My team recently linked our google analytics premium account with our double click for publishers account.  Now when I go to the google analytics website, I can create a report and get the following metrics per page:

DFP Revenue
Publisher Revenue
DFP Backfill Revenue
AdX Revenue

The issue is that I want to consume this data via the reporting API.  I see that I can use the metric "ga:adxRevenue" to get the AdX Revenue.  My question is, how can I get the other 3 types of revenue from the reporting API?  I experimented by trying "ga:dfpRevenue" but got the following error:

GOOGLE ANALYTICS FAIL: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%[id purposefully left out]&start-date=2016-06-03&end-date=2016-06-03&metrics=ga%3Apageviews%2Cga%3AuniquePageviews%2Cga%3Asessions%2Cga%3AadxRevenue%2Cga%3AdfpRevenue&dimensions=ga%3Adate%2Cga%3ApagePath&start-index=1&max-results=10000&sort=-ga%3Apageviews&filters=ga%3ApagePath%3D%7E%2Fnews%2F%7C%2Flists: (400) Unknown metric(s): ga:dfpRevenue

What metrics do I need to use to get this to work?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: You need to simultaneously query the campaign and analytics and cross compare both to get your desired value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that metric is currently not supported.

- See the [dimensions and metric explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) for the complete list of supported dimensions and metrics.
- Your application can always subscribe to the [Metadata API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/) to stay up to date with the latest dimensions and metrics.

Comment: Hi Matt! All the dfp metric seems to be nonfunctional but is listed on the API docs? I really need some help..